# What's the best way to find a Tardigrade

Tags: zoology, microbiology

So I have a school science project on the best sample to look under a microscope, so I want to bring in a Tardigrade. It's winter here in Ohio, although Tardigrades are freeze tolerant I don't think there's a high chance of finding one in a cup full of snow. I heard Tardigrades live on certain fruits such as strawberries and lettuce. I just want to be 100% sure I'll bring in a Tardigrade.

Comment: P.S: It's snowy so I can't make a tardigrade habitat.

Comment: google where to buy tardigrades,you can get them online

Comment: Have you searched for where Tardigrades usually live? (should be easy to find). Please do so (since we require question askers to demonstrate some research effort, and a simple Google or Wikipedia search would likely give you a couple of starting points). Update your post with any updates and where you found the info, and then let us know what you still can't figure out. Thanks

Comment: Alright, Thanks.

Comment: If the ground wasn't frozen I would have not posted this question.

Comment: I have heard they live in moss, so one time I got some moss and tried to find tardigrades in it. This did not work. I upvoted your question because I would love to find tardigrades too. It's not fun to "get them online."

Comment: Maybe greenhouses? or Houseplants? Indoor botanical gardens (which is basically a greenhouse in museum form)? You could ask the staff there if you have one.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help everyone.